# Operadores > y < en los atributos con Jquery

Tags: jquery

Partimos de una etiqueta div con un atributo

```
<div atr="1">a</div>
```

No he encontrado un operador para este caso, quiero saber si el atributo es mayor que  X . Para añadirle la clase disabled. X es cualquier numero ejemplo 5.

```
$("div [atr<='X']").addClass('disabled');
```

El operador not equals no me sirve porque hay varios que no deben ser disabled y varios que si.

Comment: Creo que no existe el  selector *mayor que* pero aún así ¿Que diferencia hay entre los que **si**  y los que **no**?

Comment: Es una paginación y puedes escoger cuantos se muestran por pagina e irlo cambiando todo el rato. Por tanto lo que se muestran y los que no cambian en funcion cuantos quieres mostrar por pagina no es estatico

Comment: Debieras habituarte a usar las etiquetas predefinidas de HTML5. atr no es una etiqueta válida. Para eso puedes usar `data`. Para usarlo bastaría con poner `data-atr="1"` y ya estaría dentro del estándar. Para recogerlo por jquery con usar `$('elemento').data('atr')` bastaría. Un saludo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No puedes usar esos operadores dentro de un selector. Podrías hacer algo así:

```
 $( "div" ).each(function() {
   if($(this).attr("atr")<='X'){
     $( this ).addClass("disabled");
   }      
});
```

Comment: A la perfección me ha servido. Algún cambio hice, pero la idea es como tu me lo has planteado.

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de [@MikelFerreiro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/257961/16597) es correcta, pero podrías optimizar y simplificar el código aún mas usando:

- `$("div[atr]")`: para buscar solo aquellos elementos que tengan el atributo `atr`, de lo contrario estarías buscando TODOS los `div` en la página.
- [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/Filter/): para filtrar los elemento que no cumplen con la condición y aprovechar el [`chaining`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp) para aplicar `.addClass` al resultado.

#### Demo

```js
$("div[atr]").filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("atr") <= 2;
}).addClass("disabled");
```

```css
div[atr] {
  color: red;
}

div[atr].disabled {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div atr="1">A</div>
<div atr="3">B</div>
<div atr="2">C</div>
<div atr="4">D</div>
<div>E</div>
```